# C# - stream question

Tags: c#, c++, stream

When I was writing some I/O routine in `C++`, I would usually make it as generic as possible, by operating on the interfaces from `<iostream>`.

*For example:*

```
void someRoutine(std::istream& stream) { ... }
```

*How should the same be done in `C#`?*

**I suspect I could write my routines based on the `System.IO.TextReader` or `System.IO.TextWriter`, but I'm not sure.**

---

Obviously I'm seeking for a same base class in `C#`, which is as generic as `std::istream` or `std::ostream` and which can be extended in many ways *(for example, as `boost::iostreams` extends the `std::` streams).*

Comment: An abstract class is about as basic as you're going to get... (though depends what you're looking for, too; there's also [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work with strings, you should take a `TextReader` or `TextWriter`.

If you want to work with bytes, you should take a `Stream`.

These classes are inherited by concrete implementations such as `FileStream`, `StringWriter`, and `NetworkStream`.

Comment: That's not exactly true.  TextReader and TextWriter operate on streams, but they are not in the inheritance chain of either Stream or FileStream.  They are the bases for StringReader and StringWriter, respectively.  For what the OP is looking to do, System.IO.Stream is the appropriate class (equivalent to a combined Input and Output Stream).

Comment: @Chris: I never said that.  I said _these_ classes.

Comment: I misinterpreted your answer then, apologies.  I took "These classes" to mean all of the classes mentioned above, I assume the OP could have made the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) if you only care about bytes. `TextReader` / `TextWriter` are for when you know the underlying data to be text.

Answer (score 1):

The base class *is* `Stream`.  MemoryStream, FileStream, etc. inherit from this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the C# function taking a Stream ( System.IO.Stream ) as in C++. If this is appropriate depends on the function you write.